# Specify valid controllers for a route

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I've to provide two Web API controllers `PublicController` and `PrivateController` for our system. These should have the following routes:

`/public/{controller}/{id}`

and

`/private/{controller}/{id}`

On the firewall, all requests to `/private` are blocked and only available from inside the network. But by convention, both of my controllers are available for both routes, so I could request `PrivateController` (which should only be available under `/private`) with the url `/public/PrivateController/1`.

Is there a way to specify valid controllers for a route, so that the `PrivateController` is only available for the private route? Or are there some other practices to fullfill this requirement?

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Can you show some code how your routes look like at the moment.

Comment: I don't have any code actually. The code I mentioned in the question is some sample code to explain my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `constraints` parameter to provide restrictions on the controller name in the simplest case with a very simple regular expression:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "private",
    routeTemplate: "api/private/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { controller = @"private" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "public",
    routeTemplate: "api/public/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { controller = @"public" }
);
```

So the now the "private" route only accept the controller which named Private and the "public" route will only accept the controller which named Public. If you have multiple public and private controllers you can easily extend the regex to match them.

If the regex is not enough for your needs you can create your custom route contaraint with implementing the `IRouteConstraint` interface. You can find an example implantation [In this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs).